# Code Build Access denied while downloading artifact from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

My CodeBuild is configured with CodePipeline. S3 is my artifact store. I continue to get an Access denied message despite having attached IAM roles with sufficient access.

Screenshot of the error message

[image: Code Build Error message]

I have already checked the service role associated with Codebuild. It has the following policy attached to it.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:logs:ap-southeast-1:682905754632:log-group:/aws/codebuild/Build",
            "arn:aws:logs:ap-southeast-1:682905754632:log-group:/aws/codebuild/Build:*"
        ],
        "Action": [
            "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "logs:CreateLogStream",
            "logs:PutLogEvents"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::codepipeline-ap-southeast-1-*"
        ],
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:GetObjectVersion"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

But when I test it using the IAM policy validator I get the following error message.

[image]

Based on the accepted answer to this question the policy that I currently have should allow me to get the artifacts from S3 without any problems - [AWS Codebuild fails while downloading source. Message: Access Denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48225778/aws-codebuild-fails-while-downloading-source-message-access-denied)

How do I get rid of the access denied message?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This generally happens when you have a CodeBuild project already and you integrate it to a CodePipeline pipeline. When you integrate a Codebuild project with CodePipeline, the project will retrieve it's source from the CodePipeline Source output. Source output will be stored in the artifact store location, which is an S3 bucket, either a default bucket created by CodePipeline or one you specify upon pipeline creation.

So, you will need to provide permissions to the CodeBuild Service role to access the CodePipline bucket in S3. The role will require permissions to put S3 objects in the bucket, as well as get objects.

Policy which i tried and same is working:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
{
  "Sid": "CodeBuildDefaultPolicy",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "codebuild:*",
    "iam:PassRole"
  ],
  "Resource": "*"      
},
{
  "Sid": "CloudWatchLogsAccessPolicy",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "logs:FilterLogEvents",
    "logs:GetLogEvents"
  ],
  "Resource": "*"
},
{
  "Sid": "S3AccessPolicy",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "s3:CreateBucket",
    "s3:GetObject",
    "s3:List*",
    "s3:PutObject"
  ],
  "Resource": "*"
  }
 ]
}
```

**Policy Simulator**

[image]

[AWS Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/setting-up.html#setting-up-service-role)

Comment: Hey! Thanks for helping me with this. So effectively what I need to do is add this policy to the code pipeline role and this should work, right? I need to allow CodePipeline role access to the codebuild role? Did I get that right?

Comment: You need an AWS CodeBuild service role so that AWS CodeBuild can interact with dependent AWS services (Code Pipeline) on your behalf

Comment: The policy I posted is from my codebuild service role and it has permissions to getObject and putObject from the code-pipeline. I will try creating a new CodePipeline with codebuild and see if the problem happens again.

Comment: Yes and please do refer the following link which will help to understand the service role and how to use AWS CodePipeline with AWS CodeBuild https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/how-to-create-pipeline.html

Comment: I created a new pipeline and tried it out. Still the same problem. I followed the exact steps given on the link. Also, made sure I created a new build from the CodePipeline console instead of CodeBuild.

Comment: can you please post your latest policy document along with the results from the Policy simulator in your initial edit post

Comment: I managed to solve it finally. I copy pasted the S3 access privileges from your policy to mine and I was finally able to read the S3 bucket! Not sure if that is the right way to do it but it definitely solved the problem for now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I had the issue, where I had the get, getobjectversion and put already there. I added "s3:List*"... I'm pretty sure the codebuild doesn't need the createBucket permissions :)