# AWS CodePipeline - Insufficient permissions Unable to access the artifact error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline

Trying to create and run an AWS CodePipeline that pulls from Github, builds and deploys to an EC2 instance. The pipeline is as follows:

Source (Github) -> Build (AWS CodeBuild) -> Deploy (AWS CodeDeploy)

The source and build steps both succeed. However, deploy fails consistently giving the following error:

---

Insufficient permissions
Unable to access the artifact with Amazon S3 object key '[redacted]-2nd-test-pip/BuildArtif/IbiHzen' located in the Amazon S3 artifact bucket 'codepipeline-us-east-1-[redacted]'. The provided role does not have sufficient permissions.

---

Below is the IAM policy for the CodeBuild service role policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:362490217134:log-group:/aws/codebuild/[Redacted]-Build-Project",
                "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:362490217134:log-group:/aws/codebuild/[Redacted]-Build-Project:*"
            ],
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::codepipeline-us-east-1-*"
            ],
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::codepipeline-us-east-1-[Redacted]/*"
            ],
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The CodePipeline service role created by the pipeline wizard has assigned S3 full access:

```
            "Action": [
                "elasticbeanstalk:*",
                "ec2:*",
                "elasticloadbalancing:*",
                "autoscaling:*",
                "cloudwatch:*",
                "s3:*",
                "sns:*",
                "cloudformation:*",
                "rds:*",
                "sqs:*",
                "ecs:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
```

I have confirmed numerous times that the artifact referenced in the pipeline deploy step matches the artifact created by the build step.

If I go and look at path referenced, there is not a directory or zip file (not sure which SHOULD be there, but neither is) with that name. Additionally, a zip file is generated during the build, but it is never named what the deploy step expects.

I've also gone into the build project and attempted builds using other artifact configurations, but they seem to be ignored when running the build through CodePipeline.

Disclaimer: I've seen similar questions posted here and elsewhere on the interwebs, but each of them deal with ECS or another situation that differs from mine. Thank you for your help

Comment: I ran into a very similar problem with CodeDeploy on EC2. Check out if this question is of use to you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53790842/understanding-iam-policies

Comment: Also, it might be helpful if you update your question with the IAM access policy, role permissions that your CodePipeline is using.

Comment: Thank you @Sashi. I did attempt what you suggested with no success. I have also updated the question to include policy details.

Comment: This is due to artifact not being created. Refer this answer(https://stackoverflow.com/a/60983084/4842112) and article - https://medium.com/@shanikae/insufficient-permissions-unable-to-access-the-artifact-with-amazon-s3-247f27e6cdc3

Answer (score 9):

The issue was unrelated to roles/policies. As mentioned, the expected zip file did not exist in the S3 bucket. This was due to an invalid artifact files path specified in the buildspec. Once corrected, the zip file is created and the deploy no longer fails on this error. Seems odd to me that CodePipeline would allow the build to report as completed successfully without validating that the files created as the artifact and passed to the deploy step were, in fact, created.